# react-native doesn't run the app on ios 14

Tags: ios, react-native

i need some help on the react-native 0.61.5.I run the app on iOS 14 it show me a blank screen can someone help me to fix this issue .

Comment: This might be caused by you not having the upgraded version of xcode. Please provide more information. - logs,
- screenshot,
- your code,

Comment: i'm using xcode 12 the last version

Comment: Is it possible for you to upgrade to react-native 63 and compile it with xcode 14?